# Javascript function not firing with html onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am battling to get my javascript function to fire when a button is clicked on my html page.
My html code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>VLA SYSTEM</title>
        <a href="logout.php" onclick="logout();" style="float:right;">Logout</a>
        <script
            type ="text/JavaScript" src="logout.js"></script>

        </head>
    <body>
<form>
      <script
          type ="text/JavaScript" src="regGen.js"></script>
          <script
          type="text/JavaScript" src="submit.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="btnAssign" value="Assign Owner To Registration Number..." onclick="submit()">
```

My javascript code snippet:

```
function submit() {
    window.alert("Information Captured And Stored To Database!");
}
```

The idea is that, when the user clicks on the button, the alert should fire informing the user that information has been captured, however, I am unable to get this alert to appear.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, unintuitively, inline handlers essentially implicitly use `with (this)` for the element that triggered the event, *and* for the parent element, and so on:

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" name="btnAssign" value="Assign Owner To Registration Number..."
    onclick="console.log(submit === document.querySelector('form').submit)"
  >
</form>
```

And `form.submit` is a built-in function will submit the form.

Either use a different function name, like `doAlert`:

```
onclick="doAlert()"
```

and

```
function doAlert() {
  window.alert("Information Captured And Stored To Database!");
}
```

Or attach the listener properly using Javascript instead (inline handlers are pretty bad practice, and can result in unintuitive behavior like you're seeing):

```
document.querySelector('input[name="btnAssign"]).addEventListener('click', submit);
```